# Sharepoint Rest Api ShareObject method

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to share a file/folder with users through a rest call. The Sharing permission of the site has already been set.
I found out about SP.Web.ShareObject method but I'm getting a "Couldn't resolve the users" error message.
Here's the body:

```
{
   "url":"https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/Shared Documents/example.docx",
   "emailBody":"Example body",
   "emailSubject":"Example subject",
   "peoplePickerInput":"example@hotmail.com",
   "includeAnonymousLinkInEmail":false,
   "roleValue":"0",
   "sendEmail":true,
   "groupId":"0",
   "useSimplifiedRoles":false,
   "propagateAcl":false
}
```

The call information (no-syntax):

```
Method : post
Headers : (accept, application/json; odata=verbose)
          (authorization, bearer + accesstoken)

url: https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/_api/SP.Web.ShareObject
```

Apparently in the past the "peoplePickerInput" parameter was an object but now it's just a string. I think it's something to do with that.

Does anyone know how to use this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you update your "peoplePickerInput" property like below:

```
"peoplePickerInput" => "[{'Key' : 'i:0#.f|membership|exampleuser@yoursharepointsite.com', 'Description' : 'exampleuser@yoursharepointsite.com', 'DisplayText' : 'Example user', 'EntityType' : 'User', 'ProviderDisplayName' : 'Tenant', 'ProviderName' : 'Tenant', 'IsResolved' : true, 'EntityData' : {'Title' : '', 'MobilePhone' : '', 'Department' : '', 'Email' : 'exampleuser@yoursharepointsite.com'}, 'MultipleMatches' : []}]"
```

Even though the property is a string but it should a string of JSON object, as per my understanding.